# publish information to facebook(iPhone)

Tags: iphone, facebook

I used the FBStreamDialog to publish information to facebook wall in iPhone
the Dialog textField is empty.

How can I to set the Dialog's textField by other value?

I mean, I have a textFiled then I put something, and click button awake FBStreamDialog
how can I initial the `FBStreamDialog` textField == my input textField

Answer (score 1):

Facebook frowns upon status messages that are not specifically set by the user. You certainly can do what you are trying via the graph call, however Facebook monitors this closely and if caught they will shut down your app and any app developer accounts associated with the app.